# Adding additional VBA module creates Compile Error when running previously working module

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, compilation

Trying to incorporate two modules into an excel sheet and am running into an issue that I haven't been able to diagnose. Independently the modules work but when both are in the file it gives me a "Compile Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" with the Sub line highlighted in debug. I don't know enough to diagnose further and was hoping I could get some guidance here.

Module 1 - creates new file and email

```
    Dim fPO As String
    Dim fDate As Date
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim POFile As String
    Dim Template As String
    Dim yearfolder As String
    Dim monthfolder As String
    Dim newfolderpath As String
    Dim FileName As String

Sub CreatePOFile()
'
' Creates new file for each PO
'

'


    fPO = Range("C4").Value
    fDate = Date - 3 'adjust to change date used in file name
    fPath = "\\Kforce.com\Group\TAMPA\CORP\Strategic Accounts\Strategic Accounts Operations\CLIENT REPORTS\HP\HP Weekly PO Reporting" 'adjust where file is saved
    Template = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    monthfolder = Format(fDate, "mm. mmmm YYYY")
    yearfolder = Format(fDate, "YYYY")
    newfolderpath = fPath & "\" & yearfolder & "\" & monthfolder
    FileName = fPO & " Weekly Report as of " & Format(fDate, "yyyymmdd")

'
'
'

    'Format pivot table header
    Rows("7:7").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    'Create new workbook and save individual PO file. Creates new folders if nonexistant
    Workbooks.Add

    If Len(Dir(fPath & "\" & yearfolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir fPath & "\" & yearfolder
    End If
    If Len(Dir(fPath & "\" & yearfolder & "\" & monthfolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir fPath & "\" & yearfolder & "\" & monthfolder
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=newfolderpath & "\" & FileName, FileFormat:=51
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    POFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    'Copy Pivot information to new file
    Windows(Template).Activate
    Range("B7").Select
    ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select

    Windows(POFile).Activate
    Range("B7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveSheet.Name = fPO

    'Formatting PO File and adding information fields
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Weekly PO Report"
    With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri Light"
        .Size = 18
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
    End With

    Range("B4").Value = "PO Number:"
    Range("B5").Value = "Date Range:"

    Range("B4:B5").Select
    With Selection
        .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
        .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .Interior.TintAndShade = 0
        .Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
        .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .Font.TintAndShade = 0
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With

    Range("C4").Value = fPO
    Range("C5").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(MIN(C[-1]),""m/d/yyyy"")&"" - ""&TEXT(MAX(C[-1]),""m/d/yyyy"")"
    Range("C4:C5").Select
    With Selection
        .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
        .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .Interior.TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 15
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    Range("A1").Select


    'asks if email should be created
    Dim answer As Integer

    answer = MsgBox("Would you like to create email?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Email Option")

    If answer = vbYes Then EmailFile
    Else
    End If

End Sub

Sub EmailFile()

    'Creates email with file attached
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim MailBody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    MailBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt'>" & "Hello,<br><br>" & _
                "Attached you will find the weekly report for " & fPO & "." & "<br><br>" & _
                "If you have any questions or discrepancies, please let me know!<br><br>Regards," & "</p>"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .Display
        .to = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = FileName
        .HTMLbody = MailBody & .HTMLbody
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Module 2 - formats raw data tab for ease of use

```
Sub Format()
'
' Removes previous raw data and deletes the blank rows so the table doesn't need to be resized upon copy paste of new data
'

    On Error Resume Next
    Rows("4:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    Range("raw[Last Name]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Range("A3:Z3").ClearContents
    Range("A3").Activate


End Sub

Sub Refresh()

If Range("A3") = "" Then

MsgBox ("Please paste new data before clicking Refresh.")

Else
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: In Module 2, `Sub Format()` overwrites the built-in function used in Module 1 (`monthfolder = Format(fDate, "mm. mmmm YYYY")`). Rename `Sub Format()` to `Sub Format1()` and update the code where needed

Comment: Wow - glad I spent like 4 hours trying to research what the heck was wrong. Thank you kindly! I guess the lesson here is not to name sub's with function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Module 2, `Sub Format()` overwrites the built-in function used in Module 1

```
(monthfolder = Format(fDate, "mm. mmmm YYYY"))
```

Rename `Sub Format()` to `Sub Format1()` and update the code where needed

A simple way to determine a conflict is to click inside the function name and pressing F1 to activate the help module - it should come back with "Keyword Not Found"